# How do i add a dota after first header in my TOC

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

Currently, I have

1 ABC

1.1 ABC

I Want

1. ABC

1.1 ABC

Answer (score 1):

First you need to update styles to be corresponding to your demanded formatting  after doing this:

1- select first title then from multilevel list chose desired formatting.
2- regarding to second level paragraph go to multilevel list then (define new multi level list)
- just remove the dot after second number.
- hit ok.[image]